# Is there a way to do wj with aggration on columns from the left table?

Tags: kdb, qpython, rethinkdb-python, qpython3

I have below code. `weight` is from the right table, and the aggregation works. `weightLeft` is from the left table, and the aggregation doesn't work. Is it possible to make `weightLeft` works?

```
t:([]sym:3#`ibm;time:10:01:01 10:01:04 10:01:08;price:200 201 205;weightLeft:3 4 5);

price:101 103 103 104 104 107 108 107 108;
weight:10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30;
q:([]sym:`ibm; time:10:01:01+til 9; price:price; weight:weight);
f:`sym`time;
w:-2 1+\:t.time;

wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);({sum x*y};`price;`weight))]; // OK
wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);({sum x*y};`price;`weightLeft))]; // failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to use columns from the left table in that manner. If you have use the identity operator `::` as your aggregation function you can see how kdb interprets that column as a null symbol, hence the type error.

`````
q)wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);(::;`weightLeft))]
sym time     price weightLeft
-----------------------------
ibm 10:01:01 204   ``
ibm 10:01:04 414   ````
ibm 10:01:08 430   ````
`````

For your use case could you aggregate on `price` then multiply by `weightLeft` afterwards?

```
q)update price*weightLeft from wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price))]
sym time     price weightLeft
-----------------------------
ibm 10:01:01 612   3
ibm 10:01:04 1656  4
ibm 10:01:08 2150  5
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but they are not exactly the same. I need to do sum(a*b), but by doing this way it's sum(a)*sum(b), so they are different...